# How to open fragment class through intent in another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, slidingdrawer

My SlidingScreenActivity code is,

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }
public void displayView(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment=new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment=new Mywallet();
            break;
        case 3:

            fragment=new AboutUsFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        Log.e("SlidingMainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Another Activity button listener,

```
btnWallet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent mIntent=new Intent(this,SlidingScreenActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                }
            });
```

How can i open`MyWallet fragment` that i have already declared in case 2: in `SlidingScreenActivity.class` ,when click on button in another activity through Intent? 
could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlidingScreenActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    displayView(getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 2));
}
```

Another Activity button listener:

```
btnWallet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent mIntent=new Intent(this,SlidingScreenActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", 2);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });
```